# A proof that a given function is an $R$-module epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The question is given in the following picture:

[image]

My answer is as follows:

I will name the function $\pi$,to prove that the function is an R-module epimorphism I will prove that it is an R-module homomorphism and that it is Onto.

First.let r,s,x $\in R$ & a \in A.

1-$\pi(r + s) = (r + s)a = ra + sa (since A is a an R-module) = \pi(r) + \pi(s).$

2-$\pi(sa) = r(sa) = r\pi(a)$.

Second. let  y $\in$ Ra, we want to show that there exist $x \in R$ such that:
$$y = \pi(x),$$

Since $y \in Ra$, then $y=rx$, for some $r \in R,$ then $y = \pi(x)$ as required.

Is my proof right?

Thanks!!

Comment: Note that $sa$ and $a$ are elements of $A$, not $R$, so $\pi(sa)$ and $\pi(a)$ are not defined. Similarly if $r,x\in R$ then $rx\in R$ cannot equal $y\in A$.